# Code Igniter Form Validation: not required but min length

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I'm working with Code Igniter to validate a form. I would like a field to be optional, but if the user provides a value, it should have a minimum length.

As a rule, I have mentionned

```
min_length[500]
```

If I post my form with an empty value, it returns me an error regarding the size of the input being too short.

How can I meet my requirement?

Thank you,
Aurélien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a condition on that specific field, like if the field is not empty :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field_1', 'Field 1', 'required');
if (!empty($this->input->post('field_2')))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('field_2', 'Field 2', 'min_length[500]');
}
```